# fl <- as.factor(sml) & gset$description Code Pairing is Not Working - Dataset Has Too Many Rows

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I am having a slight problem with trying to fix an error. My dataset has 30 samples with 38.830 features. I copied and pasted the program code that is producing the error that I am trying to fix below:

```
> colnames(pData(pehnoData(gset)))[1:40]
"At positions 39 & 40 the output results are both NA & NA"

> pData(phenoData(gset))[ , c(11,12)]

           characteristics_ch1.1        characteristics_ch1.2
GSM1690577       tissue: Tonsils cell type: mononuclear cells
GSM1690578       tissue: Tonsils cell type: mononuclear cells
GSM1690579       tissue: Tonsils cell type: mononuclear cells
GSM1690580       tissue: Tonsils cell type: mononuclear cells
GSM1690581       tissue: Tonsils cell type: mononuclear cells
GSM1690582       tissue: Tonsils cell type: mononuclear cells
GSM1690583       tissue: Tonsils cell type: mononuclear cells
GSM1690584       tissue: Tonsils cell type: mononuclear cells
GSM1690585       tissue: Tonsils cell type: mononuclear cells
GSM1690586       tissue: Tonsils cell type: mononuclear cells
GSM1690587       tissue: Tonsils cell type: mononuclear cells
GSM1690588       tissue: Tonsils cell type: mononuclear cells
GSM1690589       tissue: Tonsils cell type: mononuclear cells
GSM1690590       tissue: Tonsils cell type: mononuclear cells
GSM1690591       tissue: Tonsils cell type: mononuclear cells
GSM1690592       tissue: Tonsils cell type: mononuclear cells
GSM1690593       tissue: Tonsils cell type: mononuclear cells
GSM1690594       tissue: Tonsils cell type: mononuclear cells
GSM1690595       tissue: Tonsils cell type: mononuclear cells
GSM1690596       tissue: Tonsils cell type: mononuclear cells
GSM1690597       tissue: Tonsils cell type: mononuclear cells
GSM1690598       tissue: Tonsils cell type: mononuclear cells
GSM1690599       tissue: Tonsils cell type: mononuclear cells
GSM1690600       tissue: Tonsils cell type: mononuclear cells
GSM1690601       tissue: Tonsils cell type: mononuclear cells
GSM1690602       tissue: Tonsils cell type: mononuclear cells
GSM1690603       tissue: Tonsils cell type: mononuclear cells
GSM1690604       tissue: Tonsils cell type: mononuclear cells
GSM1690605       tissue: Tonsils cell type: mononuclear cells
GSM1690606       tissue: Tonsils cell type: mononuclear cells

> tr <- levels(unique(pData(phenoData(gset))[12])[,1])

> tr1 <- gsub("b-cell subset: ","", tr[1])
> tr2 <- gsub("b-cell subset: ","", tr[2])
> tr3 <- gsub("b-cell subset: ","", tr[3])

> sml <- c("C0","C0","C0","C0","C1","C1","C1","C1","C2","C2","C2","C2");
> ex <- exprs(gset)
> qx <-as.numeric(quantile(ex, c(0., 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.99, 1.0), na.rm=T))

> LogC <- (qx[5] > 100) || (qx[6] - qx[1] > 50 && qx[2] > 0) || (qx[2] > 0 && qx[2] < 1 && qx[4] > 1 && qx[4] < 2)
> if (LogC) {ex[which(ex <= 0)] <- NaNexprs(gset) <- log2(ex) }

> par(mfrow=c(1,2))
> hist(2^exprs(gset), breaks=25)
> hist(exprs(gset), breaks=25)

> fl <- as.factor(sml)
> gset$description <- fl

Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L,  : 
  replacement has 12 rows, data has 30
```

I have been told that this error is possibly subsettable and could be occurring because I might have "NA" in my data. A solution to eliminate the "NA" in my dataset was to put this code as the beginning of the dataset

```
gset <- na.omit(gset)
```

I used this code at the beginning, ran the other codes, and still produced this error. My questions are these:

1. Is there a specific code function to increase the number of replacement rows to fit and correctly process my dataset?
2. Is there a specific code syntax method that I could use to reduce the number of rows my dataset has so that the gset$description <- fl will work? Could I modify the code `fl <- as.factor(sml)` or modify the code `sml <- c("C0","C0","C0","C0","C1","C1","C1","C1","C2","C2","C2","C2");`?

   - I have tried to modify the sml code, but I received a different error saying that the data is not subsettleable.

If anyone could offer any direction or answers to any of my questions if or when they have the available chance I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I can't address all of this, because I can't figure out what you are trying to do from your code.  When you define `sml`, it's a vector of length 12.  We can define this multiple ways, but it's always length 12:

```
# equivalent definitions for `sml`, if you like them better:
sml <- rep(c("C0", "C1", "C2"), each = 4)
sml <- paste0("C", rep(0:2, each = 4))
```

The length of this variable is not changed by making it a factor.  All that changes is how the variable exists in memory.  A factor has two components - a vector of characters (the levels), and a vector of integers which map to the characters, telling you which level of the factor belongs in a given spot.  So `fl` still has length 12.

Now, you're trying to assign `fl` to `gset$description`, which is (from https://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/Biobase/inst/doc/ExpressionSetIntroduction.pdf - I'm very rusty on bioconductor, and probably out of date as well), accessing `phenoData(gset)`.  According to the error, you have 30 rows in this data set - one for each sample.  What you appear to be trying to do is assign each of the 30 samples a value of `C0`, `C1`, or `C2`.  If that is not what you are trying to do, you need to clearly explain what you are trying to accomplish so we can help you on this.  Otherwise, you need to explain how `C0`, `C1`, and `C2` should be assigned to the samples so they can be assigned appropriately.

One last thing.  These are the *only* lines of code which affect `sml` and `fl`.

```
sml <- c("C0","C0","C0","C0","C1","C1","C1","C1","C2","C2","C2","C2") # can be rewritten as above
fl <- as.factor(sml)
gset$description <- fl
```

Everything else has no affect on `sml`, `fl`, or `gset`.  While `gset <- na.omit(gset)` might remove some elements from your exrpession set, I'm guessing it will remove features, not samples - which will have no effect on your overall error.

Comment: That is what I am trying to do. I was following a R Program Microarray Gene Expression Tutorial and code processed similar to what you mentioned were not accurately described in the tutorial and why to use them. I will try this approach to see if it works (it probably will) and I will mention what you said when I create a more accurate tutorial for the data I am analyzing. Thank you so much again and much success!